# Webpack - Postcss nesting not working used as suggested

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, postcss, postcss-loader

I have this simple css that uses a nested rule.

```
.root {
  background: var(--color-accent);
  padding: 0.8rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
    background: var(--color-purple);
  }
}
```

I am using `postcss-loader`in Webpack as loader.

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
  },
```

And this is my `postcss.config.js` file. It is the same as the code used in https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested#usage

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["autoprefixer", "postcss-nested"],
};
```

The css file is loaded, but the nested rule is stil as it is. The browser does not recognize it.

What to do to achive the following?

```
.root {
  background: var(--color-accent);
  padding: 0.8rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--color-white);
  text-decoration: none;
}


.root:hover {
  background: var(--color-purple);
}
```

CSS variables are defined in the genereated css (colors works). The **postcss.config.js** is file loaded too.

A screenshoot of the nested css in Chrome.

[image]

## Update

I set up a similar project on **Codesandbox**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-tree-chz7y3

Post-css-nesting works neither.

```
module.exports = () => ({
    plugins: [
        require("postcss-preset-env")({
            stage: 3,
            features: {
                "color-mod-function": { unresolved: "warn" },
                "nesting-rules": true,

                "custom-properties": {
                    preserve: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: Are your color variables defined anywhere? Are those definitions included in the generated css?

Comment: Are you sure webpack is reading your config?

Comment: I reproduced your steps here and it worked for me. Could you put a sample from your project into Codesandbox or similar and share it with us?

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha did you use Typescript or Javascript?

Comment: @mahan I tried both. Will see your project later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `create-react-app`. I'm afraid it didn't support `postcss.config.js` yet, as seen in [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9604#issuecomment-782898901).

I think you'll need to refactor your code to some extent. For example, you could try using [`craco`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) to override CRA configuration.